# What difference does it make of accessing through "Object" and through Object.constructor?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
    var obj2 = new Object();
    
    console.log(Object.isExtensible(obj2)); //returns 'true'
    console.log(obj2.constructor.isExtensible()); //returns 'false'
```

Could anyone explain why the first console print returns boolean 'true' and the second one 'false' and what difference it makes if isExtensible() is called either way.

Comment: `obj2.constructor.isExtensible()` is the same as `Object.isExtensible()` - well, the difference you're not passing an object into it…

Answer (score 0):

The `.constructor` of an instance refers to the class / function that instantiates an instance. Since you're doing

```
var obj2 = new Object();
```

this means that `obj2.constructor` is the same as Object.

So

```
obj2.constructor.isExtensible()
```

is calling `Object.isExtensible`, but without an argument. `isExtensible` requires an argument. If you pass it the `obj2`, it'll do what you expect:

```js
var obj2 = new Object();

console.log(Object.isExtensible(obj2)); //returns 'true'
console.log(obj2.constructor.isExtensible(obj2));
console.log(obj2.constructor === Object);
```

But that's still confusing. I'd recommend never using `obj2.constructor` - just use `Object` instead, it'll make more sense.

Usually, you'd probably only want to use the `.constructor` property when you don't already have a reference to the class - otherwise, it's easier to just reference the class.

Comment: `obj2.constructor` might be appropriate of `obj2` could be an instance of a subclass whose constructor has a custom `isExtensible()` method.

Comment: `isExtensible` is not something that should be shadowed unless the developer was deliberately intending to confuse future readers of the code, IMO. The [native method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isExtensible) is well known, something with the same name that does something different would be quite weird.

Comment: Yes, it's not really a realistic thing to do. I was just trying to come up with a theoretical reason why one might use `obj.constructor` to avoid hard-coding a specific constructor.

Comment: @Barmar  I wasn't afraid to look around and play with javascript to learn what functions/properties such as "constructor" do inside of objects. Other than that this post has summed up the answer to my question pretty darn well.

Comment: @CertainPerformance The only reason why i was "deliberately intending to confuse future readers" is because i didn't accept your question as the answer. Either that or he's a bit too paranoid.

Comment: @syclone Don't worry, you're not - you're not shadowing `isExtensible`, which is the theoretical I was referring to.